# Convergent of $\frac {\ln n} {n^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {\ln n} {n^p},$$ 
$\ p \in \Bbb N$, convergent or divergent, and how to prove it??

I think I can use the integral test but maybe another test is easier than the integral test. Can I use two cases, $p>1$ and $p<1$?

Comment: Please edit and supply missing information, like for which p.

Comment: Is p inside the ln(n^p) or outside, (ln(n))^p? If it's inside, you can use ln(n^p) = p ln(n)

Comment: @JonathanWheeler it is             (ln n)/ (n^p)

Comment: You can compare it to another series. In particular, this one is a Bertrand series ($\frac{1}{n^a \log n^b}$) with $a = p$ and $b = -1$. A Bertrand series is convergent if $a > 1$ (or if $a = 1$ and $b > 1/2$), you'd need $p > 1$ so that your series converges.

Answer (score 2):

If $p\le1$, you can use the fact that $\ln n\gt1$ for $n\gt2$ to compare $\sum{\ln n\over n^p}$ to $\sum{1\over n}$.

If $p\gt1$, you can write $p=1+2r$ with $r\gt0$ and use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ln n\over n^r}=0$ to compare $\sum{\ln n\over n^p}$ to $\sum{1\over n^{1+r}}$.

Comment: The case p <=1 it is divergent since 1/n <=ln n/n^p but the case p> 1 how ?

Comment: @Tasneem, in the $p\gt1$ case, $\ln n/n^p\lt1/n^{1+r}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.